# Get the exact Width and Height of webbrowser

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, c#-3.0, wpf-controls, silverlight-3.0

I've a local HTML, i need to show to the users. But my question is i need to get exact Height and Width of the active WebBrowser control.

Example of Code:

```
<phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="768" Width="480" Grid.Row="1" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

I need to get the Height and Width of the above control in Pixels.

Please help!
Pavan

Comment: The size of the _browser_ or the size of the _document_ or the size of the _text_?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the control's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the height of the actual content displayed (the html webpage), you can inject `JavaScript` as seen here: [Displaying HTML Content in Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx)

I've only used this with `NavigateToString().` It might work still if you are using Navigate(), if you NavigateToString() right after `LoadCompleted`.

If you are only displaying one page, you could just download the content of the page via `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient`, and then, inject JavaScript and use `NavigateToString().` I've used that method too with success.